# Python 2/3 `imaplib` extension library, `imaplibext`

Tags: python, library, email

Back again for more <s>punishment</s> improvement advice.

Basically, [stemming from my dislike of how standard `imaplib.IMAP4` mailbox interaction commands functioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631422/mark-a-single-imap-message-as-unread), I made an extension library for `imaplib`, called [`imaplibext`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imaplibext) (on PyPI now), which takes the existing `IMAP4` commands that have UID-equivalents, and actually *use* the UID-equivalent commands.  While this is a very evil approach to a very simple problem, it makes code a little easier to understand for number of different projects I work on.

I'm looking for a general review here, as well as Py2/Py3 cross-compatibility concerns.  While I don't have any *specific* concerns as everything seems to behave well and work as I expect it to, I'm sure I'm doing stupid things that I'm overlooking.

Suggestions for improvement of this already-functioning code is welcome.  The actual code part for this is attached below, but the full package itself can be found on the [github repository](https://github.com/teward/imaplibext/tree/97b8f4ddca2aeb3bf080180018e36403b13249a0) as well.

---

```
import imaplib
import socket
from typing import Union, Tuple, AnyStr, List, Any
import sys


class IMAP4(imaplib.IMAP4):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_PORT, timeout=None, maxbytes=None):
        # type: (AnyStr, int) -> None
        # Override standard __init__ - we need to add a timeout option and a maxbytes option.

        # This timeout option is used below in the 'open' function override.
        if timeout:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

        # This maxbytes option is used below to override the max bytes allowed to be returned from UID commands and
        # others if defined.  Otherwise it leaves it at the 10000 default.
        if maxbytes:
            imaplib._MAXLINE = maxbytes

        imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
        return  # PEP compliance

    def copy(self, message_set, new_mailbox):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Copy 'message_set' messages onto end of 'new_mailbox'.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.copy(message_set, new_mailbox)
        """

        # conn.uid('COPY', message_set, new_mailbox)
        return self.uid('COPY', message_set, new_mailbox)

    def fetch(self, message_set, message_parts):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, List[Tuple[Any]]]
        """Fetch (parts of) messages, using UID values.

        (typ, [data, ...]) = <instance>.fetch(message_set, message_parts)

        'message_parts' should be a string of selected parts
        enclosed in parentheses, eg: "(UID BODY[TEXT])".

        'data' are tuples of message part envelope and data.
        """

        # conn.uid('FETCH', msgset, parts)
        return self.uid('FETCH', message_set, message_parts)

    def search(self, charset, *criteria):
        # type: (Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr, tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Search mailbox for matching messages.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.search(charset, criterion, ...)

        'data' is space separated list of matching message UID numbers.
        If UTF8 is enabled, charset MUST be None.
        """

        # conn.uid('SEARCH', charset, criteria)
        return self.uid('SEARCH', charset, " ".join(criteria))

    def sort(self, sort_criteria, charset, *search_criteria):
        # type: (AnyStr, Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr,tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """IMAP4rev1 extension SORT command.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.sort(sort_criteria, charset, search_criteria, ...)
        """

        # conn.uid('SORT', '(SORT CRITERION)', 'CHARSET', 'SEARCH_CRITERIA')

        # Preprocess the search_criterion tuple - make sure all string data is split up in order
        # to make each component of the argument as its own tuple item, instead of strings with
        # spaces.
        _search_criterion = []
        for criterion in search_criteria:
            criterion = str(criterion)
            if ' ' in criterion:
                for subcriterion in criterion.split():
                    _search_criterion.append(subcriterion)
            else:
                _search_criterion.append(criterion)

        search_criteria = tuple(list(_search_criterion))

        # Preprocess the 'sort criteria' provided - make sure it's all in parentheses.
        while True:
            if sort_criteria[0] != '(':
                sort_criteria = '(' + sort_criteria
                continue

            if sort_criteria[len(sort_criteria) - 1] != ')':
                sort_criteria += ')'
                continue

            break

        # Charset is a required argument, so if we give a charset of "None", we can assume UTF-8 here.
        if not charset:
            charset = 'UTF-8'

        return self.uid('SORT', sort_criteria, charset, ' '.join(search_criteria))

    def store(self, message_set, command, flags):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Alters flag dispositions for messages in mailbox, using UID values.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.store(message_set, command, flags)
        """

        # conn.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
        return self.uid('STORE', message_set, command, flags)

    def thread(self, threading_algorithm, charset, *search_criteria):
        # type: (AnyStr, Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr, Tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, Any, list]
        """IMAPrev1 extension THREAD command.

        (type, [data]) = <instance>.thread(threading_algorithm, charset, search_criteria, ...)
        """

        # Preprocess the search_criterion tuple - make sure all string data is split up in order
        # to make each component of the argument as its own tuple item, instead of strings with
        # spaces.
        _search_criterion = []
        for criterion in search_criteria:
            criterion = str(criterion)
            if ' ' in criterion:
                for subcriterion in criterion.split():
                    _search_criterion.append(subcriterion)
            else:
                _search_criterion.append(criterion)

        search_criteria = tuple(list(_search_criterion))

        if not charset:
            charset = 'UTF-8'

        # conn.uid('THREAD', threading_algorithm, charset, search criterion)
        return self.uid('THREAD', threading_algorithm, charset, search_criteria)


# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class IMAP4_SSL(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_PORT, timeout=None, maxbytes=None,
                 keyfile=None, certfile=None, ssl_context=None):
        # type: (AnyStr, int, int, any, any, any) -> None
        # Override standard __init__ - we need to add a timeout option.
        # This timeout option is used below in the 'open' function override.
        self.timeout = timeout
        if timeout:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

        # This maxbytes option is used below to override the max bytes allowed to be returned from UID commands and
        # others if defined.  Otherwise it leaves it at the 10000 default.
        if maxbytes:
            imaplib._MAXLINE = maxbytes

        if sys.version_info.major < 3:
            if ssl_context:
                print("Warning: Defining `ssl_context` is not supported in "
                      "Python 2's IMAP_SSL implementation.")
            imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.__init__(self, host, port, keyfile, certfile)
        else:
            imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.__init__(self, host, port, keyfile, certfile, ssl_context)

        return  # PEP compliance

    def copy(self, message_set, new_mailbox):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Copy 'message_set' messages onto end of 'new_mailbox'.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.copy(message_set, new_mailbox)
        """

        # conn.uid('COPY', message_set, new_mailbox)
        return self.uid('COPY', message_set, new_mailbox)

    def fetch(self, message_set, message_parts):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, List[Tuple[Any]]]
        """Fetch (parts of) messages, using UID values.

        (typ, [data, ...]) = <instance>.fetch(message_set, message_parts)

        'message_parts' should be a string of selected parts
        enclosed in parentheses, eg: "(UID BODY[TEXT])".

        'data' are tuples of message part envelope and data.
        """

        # conn.uid('FETCH', msgset, parts)
        return self.uid('FETCH', message_set, message_parts)

    def search(self, charset, *criteria):
        # type: (Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr, tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Search mailbox for matching messages.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.search(charset, criterion, ...)

        'data' is space separated list of matching message UID numbers.
        If UTF8 is enabled, charset MUST be None.
        """

        # conn.uid('SEARCH', charset, criteria)
        return self.uid('SEARCH', charset, " ".join(criteria))

    def sort(self, sort_criteria, charset, *search_criteria):
        # type: (AnyStr, Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr,tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """IMAP4rev1 extension SORT command.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.sort(sort_criteria, charset, search_criteria, ...)
        """

        # conn.uid('SORT', '(SORT CRITERION)', 'CHARSET', 'SEARCH_CRITERIA')

        # Preprocess the search_criterion tuple - make sure all string data is split up in order
        # to make each component of the argument as its own tuple item, instead of strings with
        # spaces.
        _search_criterion = []
        for criterion in search_criteria:
            criterion = str(criterion)
            if ' ' in criterion:
                for subcriterion in criterion.split():
                    _search_criterion.append(subcriterion)
            else:
                _search_criterion.append(criterion)

        search_criteria = tuple(list(_search_criterion))

        # Preprocess the 'sort criteria' provided - make sure it's all in parentheses.
        while True:
            if sort_criteria[0] != '(':
                sort_criteria = '(' + sort_criteria
                continue

            if sort_criteria[len(sort_criteria) - 1] != ')':
                sort_criteria += ')'
                continue

            break

        # Charset is a required argument, so if we give a charset of "None", we can assume UTF-8 here.
        if not charset:
            charset = 'UTF-8'

        return self.uid('SORT', sort_criteria, charset, ' '.join(search_criteria))

    def store(self, message_set, command, flags):
        # type: (AnyStr, AnyStr, AnyStr) -> Tuple[AnyStr, list]
        """Alters flag dispositions for messages in mailbox, using UID values.

        (typ, [data]) = <instance>.store(message_set, command, flags)
        """

        # conn.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
        return self.uid('STORE', message_set, command, flags)

    def thread(self, threading_algorithm, charset, *search_criteria):
        # type: (AnyStr, Union[AnyStr, None], Union[AnyStr, Tuple]) -> Tuple[AnyStr, Any, list]
        """IMAPrev1 extension THREAD command.

        (type, [data]) = <instance>.thread(threading_algorithm, charset, search_criteria, ...)
        """

        # Preprocess the search_criterion tuple - make sure all string data is split up in order
        # to make each component of the argument as its own tuple item, instead of strings with
        # spaces.
        _search_criterion = []
        for criterion in search_criteria:
            criterion = str(criterion)
            if ' ' in criterion:
                for subcriterion in criterion.split():
                    _search_criterion.append(subcriterion)
            else:
                _search_criterion.append(criterion)

        search_criteria = tuple(list(_search_criterion))

        if not charset:
            charset = 'UTF-8'

        # conn.uid('THREAD', threading_algorithm, charset, search criterion)
        return self.uid('THREAD', threading_algorithm, charset, search_criteria)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your rather complicated part

```
    while True:
        if sort_criteria[0] != '(':
            sort_criteria = '(' + sort_criteria
            continue

        if sort_criteria[len(sort_criteria) - 1] != ')':
            sort_criteria += ')'
            continue

        break
```

may be written as

```
    if sort_criteria[0] != '(':
        sort_criteria = '(' + sort_criteria

    if sort_criteria[len(sort_criteria) - 1] != ')':
        sort_criteria += ')'
```

or - in the more Pythonic way -

```
    if not sort_criteria.startswith('('):
        sort_criteria = '(' + sort_criteria

    if not sort_criteria.endswith(')'):
        sort_criteria += ')'
```

Comment: I would also point out that negative indexes also work: `sort_criteria[-1]`.

Comment: Are you sure that your "more pythonic way" will work?  Because IIRC, `*sort_criteria` returns a tuple, *not* a string.  I'm inclined to believe that your last recommendation will explode as that's string manipulation and not tuple manipulation.  That being said, I could adapt your first suggested rewrite as a negative-index approach.

Comment: Oh, so I didn't carefully read your code. I'm glad that at least one my suggestion is useful for you.

Comment: @MarianD Actually I'm blind heh.  Rereading my code, the manipulation *can* work as a string, but eh, we'll see if this works without exploding.

Answer (score 3):

- The type-hints are incomplete for `IMAP4.__init__` and `IMAP4_SSL.__init__`.
- Try to use `typing.List` and `typing.Tuple` instead of `list` and `tuple`. The former allow you to subtype a little further, for eg. `List[str]`.
- Use `super()` instead of explicit calls: `imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)`, that would help in case of multiple inheritance.
- `Union[AnyStr, None]` can be replaced with `Optional[AnyStr]`.
- There's no need of this check: `if ' ' in criterion`. Simply split and call extend on `_search_criterion` instead of a loop and `list.append`: `_search_criterion.extend(criterion.split())`.
- The `list()` call in `tuple(list(_search_criterion))` is redundant.
- The `from` based imports should come after simple imports, plus make sure the import groups itself are sorted. Check [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Imports_formatting#Imports_formatting) and [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

  ```
  import imaplib
  import socket
  import sys
  from typing import Union, Tuple, AnyStr, List, Any
  ```
- I am not sure about `return` in `__init__` being PEP compliant.

Comment: Same to me for your last bullet point. Maybe @ThomasWard can provide a bit more explanation about that comment?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger extremely literal interpretation of PEP rules, removed.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I tried to do a super call with super(); however that never worked.  Googling the issue, it was found that IMAP4 needs the direct __init__ call, not a super(); due to whatever issues seem to be in the system.  At least, for Python 2 to work properly.  Once Py2 dies permanently, I can start making it fully modernized.

Comment: Namely, regarding the call to the explicit init calls, I did it this way because imaplib is an old-style class [per this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422724/does-pythons-imaplib-let-you-set-a-timeout) and doesn't work proper with super().  This is something I found as well when trying to develop this extension library.

Comment: Going in order from first to last, I'll make some notes.  Type hints are now completed.  I've switched to using typing.* now, though at the time of my initial module writing, there was a PyCharm type hinting bug that I was working around.  Super call won't work, imaplib is old-style, see my other comment.  Union involving None is now moved to Optional.  I've updated _search_criterion handling.  Removed the list() call in the search criterion tuple conversion.  Reordered the imports.  Also removed the `return` in `__init__`.